# OWIN/Katana Architecture

Tags: architecture, signalr, reporting, owin, katana

I'm looking to use an OWIN\Katana based architecture to replace a set of functionality for an enterprise .Net application, that looks kind of like this:

Server 
- IIS hosted reporting engine (fairly lightweight, not a whole lot of data, or DB access) 
- self-hosted soap/xml service that provides that to installed clients

Clients are Windows .net applications and are installed on the LAN.

Some improvements we are looking for are: 
- Server -> Client notification capability, similar to SignalR 
- Roaming client capability (this might require an additional component in the DMZ, and is optional for this architecture). 
- we want to self host, and not rely on IIS 
- we want to bring as much as possible under the same umbrella

Is Katana well suited for this type of implementation?
What should we use for reporting?
Is SignalR a good choice if the clients are not browsers, but .net Windows apps?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!